# Vim and gVim in Windows doesn't recognize Mongolian letters Өө and Үү

Tags: vim, vi, cyrillic

I'm trying to open end edit files with Mongolian text, written in Mongolian Cyrillic. 
In the cmd terminal and in powershell terminal if I choose Consolas font, everything is ok with Mongolian Cyrillic, letters Өө and Үү are displayed correctly.
If I open any Mongolian files in terminal Vim or gVim window, it shows them as "?" sign.
I have such an option:

```
:set guifont?
  guifont=Consolas:h9:cRUSSIAN
```

Please, give me some advise, what should I do to fix that problem?

Added:

```
set encoding=utf8
set termencoding=utf8
set guifont=Consolas:h11:cRUSSIAN          "to get proper font for Cyrillic
set fileencodings=utf8,cp1251,cp866,koi8r
"to get eng menu instead of broken Russian
set langmenu=en_US                        
let $LANG = 'en_US'
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
```

This code let's me see files properly. But I still can't type either search this letters straight in Vim, though it could be another question.

Comment: You can try at http://vi.stackexchange.com/ if no one answers here.

Comment: What's the output of `:set encoding? fileencoding?`

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in your ~/.vimrc

```
 :set encoding=utf8
 :set termencoding=utf8
 :set fileencoding=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 :set encoding=utf8
 :set termencoding=utf8
 :set fileencoding=utf8
```

Put these lines in your ~/.vimrc

Comment: Looks like you've posted the same answer twice. Please remove the duplicate.